# Set MudDrawer Width to 100% on Mobile

Tags: css, blazor, mudblazor

I have a Blazor application with a MudDrawer (from MudBlazor) and I use it as a modal dialog appearing in the right side of the screen.

However, on mobile view, I want it to have 100% width (not just approximately).

I know I can do this with custom conditional CSS but I am looking for the nicest solution and
expecting to find something nicer than that.

Here is my code:

```
<MudDrawer @bind-Open="@open" Width="375px" Anchor="Anchor.Right" Variant="DrawerVariant.Temporary">
    <MudDrawerHeader>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Header</MudText>
    </MudDrawerHeader>
    Here is some text
</MudDrawer>
```

I know I can put a method name in Width and then check the current size and set the desired width. Then if the screen size changes, I would have to detect and recalculate. That would not be a nice solution.

**So how can I make sure my MudDrawer has Width 375px but on "xs" (mobile view) it has 100% width?**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the recipe to make it work.

1. Set a variable to control with width of the drawer:

> `<MudDrawer @bind-Open="@Open" Width="@drawerWidth" Elevation="4" Anchor="Anchor.End" Variant="DrawerVariant.Temporary">`

2. The width is set to 375px by default

> `string drawerWidth = "375px";`

3. I need some code to react when a new breakpoint is set, for example if the user resizes the browser:

> ```
> Breakpoint currentBreakpoint;
> public Breakpoint CurrentBreakpoint
> {
>     get { return currentBreakpoint; }
>     set
>     {
>         currentBreakpoint = value;
>
>         if (Open)
>         {
>             // Only fiddle with sizes if the panel is currently open
>             SetSize();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

4. In order to make sure the above property is called, it must be subscribed to the breakpoint listener:

> ```
> protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
> {
>     if (firstRender)
>     {
>         var breakpointResult = await BreakpointListener.Subscribe(breakpoint =>
>         {
>             CurrentBreakpoint = breakpoint;
>         }, new ResizeOptions
>             {
>                 ReportRate = 250,
>                 NotifyOnBreakpointOnly = true,
>             });
>         CurrentBreakpoint = breakpointResult.Breakpoint;
>     }
>
>     await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
> }
> ```

5. Finally, the SetSize function will simply set the drawer to the desired size.

> ```
> public void SetSize()
> {
>     if (currentBreakpoint == Breakpoint.Xs)
>     {
>         drawerWidth = "100%";
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         drawerWidth = "375px";
>     }
>
>     StateHasChanged();
> }
> ```

(side note: for some reason the stackoverflow code formatter did not work for this code so that's why I had to to put in as quotes instead)

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a container for this kind of CSS manipulation, since the CSS of a component that you use is not open. Can you try something like it:

```
<div class="drawer-container">
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@open" Width="100%" Anchor="Anchor.Right" Variant="DrawerVariant.Temporary">
        <MudDrawerHeader>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Header</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        Here is some text
    </MudDrawer>
</div>


<style>
.drawer-container {
    width: 375px;
}

@media (max-width: 20em) { /* Change for the good breakpoint here */
    .drawer-container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and the MudDrawer is not affected by the size of the container. I double checked in DevTools in the browser. The container is the right size but the MudDrawer is whatever size it's configured to be. I guess because it's on top of the content ie. position: absolute

Comment: You mean that the `Width="100%"` in the <MudDraver> declaration is not effected?

Comment: Yes, the Width on MudDrawer is not affected by the size of the div around it. Probably because the MudDrawer is using position: absolute. I solved it with BreakpointProvider from MudBlazor and will post an answer soon, but would be more than happy to use this answer if it can be adjusted to function in this scenario. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Hi @NielsBrinch, any chance you could post your answer? Can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @alelom here you go