# Blazor: pass serialize data (with URI inside) with route parameter issue

Tags: c#, .net, url, blazor, encode

For the purpose of my application, I need to have some data pass through the URI. As it, a user can easily share the link of the page, with all data encoded inside. Everything work fine with the following:

```
    private void OnClickHandler()
    {
        var data = new List<DataModel>()
            {
                new()
                {
                    Description = "This problem",
                    // Other fields
                },
                new()
                {
                    Description = "Is annoying",
                },
            };
        var rawData = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data));

        Url = CHEMIN + rawData;
    }
```

I get a URL, and I can paste it to another Chrome window, and everything works like a charm.
**The problem occurs when I try to add a "Url" field inside my DataModel**

```
var data = new List<DataModel>()
            {
                new()
                {
                    Description = "This problem",
                    Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114505/set-muddrawer-width-to-100-on-mobile/",
                },
                new()
                {
                    Description = "Is annoying",
                    Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/",
                },
            };
```

When I try to parse the URL that I get, I have a browser issue, like the following:

[image: Chrome error page]

NB: I've tried with several browsers, same result.

I think I can understand that there is a confusion with the **System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode** method when you try to give it data with URI inside.

Is anybody is able to help me? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#routing-with-urls-that-contain-dots), we just have to add a line in the server Program.cs file.

A bit ashamed to find it right after I post the question, while I looked for the solution since two days!